# Deployd: Updating Summary Table on POST

Tags: api, events, post, deployd

I'm new to deployd.

I have a "ratings" table which basically has an `ID` and a `ratingValue` (from 1 to 5)
I have a "ratingsSummaryTable" which has `ID`, `ratingID` (from the ratings table), and five columns `n_rating1, n_rating2, n_rating3, n_rating4, n_rating5`

I want to be able to update the summary table when `ratings` has a new element (`onPost`) by

- creating the ratingsSummaryTable row should it not exist
- incrementing the corresponding n_rating&i. (where &i is the rating).

I think this would happen in the event API but I have no clue on how to do it (or even know if it's possible to do it)...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it about sql, api, what api? What did you try to do? some code?